# Virtualbox without intel-vt x not running 32-bit OS(s)

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

Im on windows 10(64x) I don't have VT-X enabled and well i can't enable it.

So how exactly do i run 32-bit os's on virtualbox?
Im trying to run MS DOS 6.0 (its 16 bit right?) but its not working

I've tried everything in "relevant posts" such as:

- Disabling all Hyper-v features
- Disabling Containers

> Etc etc

But its still not working
Any help please?

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/q/1664030/1686 answer the question somewhat?

Comment: @user1686 No nothing helpful is included. Things i already tried

Comment: Oh sorry everyone for wasting your time it was my horrible avast antivirus after all It seems like my question is a semi-dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/648158/vt-x-is-enabled-but-is-not-operational-winows-8-unable-to-run-64-bit-virtual?rq=1 I had to disable a setting or two and now it works